# How do I find the percentage change of partial variation?

Tags: bounded-variation

Z partly varies as x^2 and partly varies directly as y.If x is decreased by 20% and y is decreased by 36%, find the percentage change.

I tried to do this with how I would do percentage changes in joint variation, but I just couldn't put the numbers together as they were added not multiplied? Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that it is not clear what you mean by "partly varies".

Comment: Partial variation, so z=a(x^2)+b(y), where a and b are constants.

Comment: Really?  That's weird.  I would have guessed it meant $z=ax^2y$.  In any case you should edit your post to include this  definition.  Also:  under this definition there is no way to answer the question, there isn't enough information given.